# Importing value for number is 123,45 but 123.45 is getting stored in DB using JAVA

Tags: java, database

I am trying to assign a value to the  Number/Double field with `123,456`.

In DB, the comma (`,`) is getting converted into a dot and will be stored as `123.45`

How can I be able to keep the comma (`,`) instead of the dot (`.`)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which db are you using?

Comment: And what driver are you using? Maybe some driver or db setting that uses ',' instead of '.'. Also depends on the language for the db/app, some languages use , as a decimal separator instead of ..

Comment: I would hope the database isn't storing it as text at all. I'd hope that it's storing "a number". What is the type of the field in the database?

Comment: Hi Zlopez,  OracleDB

Comment: hi tinker,   jdbc oracle driver

Comment: Please show how you import the number and from what source, and how you assign it to the field. Also, tell us if in your country `,` marks decimal separator or thousands separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use .setString() or .updateString() to store a number, use .setInt(), .updateInt(), .setDouble(), .updateDouble() or whatever method is appropriate for the data type.